# How to fix 'java.lang.ClassCastException' when testing fragment using Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I am testing my fragments using Robolectric and I have come across a problem in some of my fragments which is causing them to become untestable. I am creating a progress bar in my Activity and then using it in my fragments. This means I am casting getActivity() to the appropriate activity (LoginActivity in this case). When this is run with Robolectric however it is giving the following error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.robolectric.shadows.support.v4.SupportFragmentTestUtil$FragmentUtilActivity cannot be cast to com.arproject.russell.ar_t.login.LoginActivity

Any help on how I could resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public static LoginFragment newInstance() {
        return new LoginFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        progressBar = ((LoginActivity) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to cast you activity to get the progress bar view. This should work as well:

```java
progressBar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
```

Comment: Thank you, I had completely overlooked removing the cast. Much appreciated